# Convergence of a series where terms involve a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I have been given the following question:

Let $ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of real, positive numbers such that $ x_n \rightarrow L $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $.
If $L>0$, prove that the following series converges:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n^4x_n+1}$$

I'm very much at a loss as to how to proceed with this...

I had initially went down the path of saying $$ \frac{n^2}{n^4x_n+1} < \frac{n^2}{n^4x_n}=\frac{1}{n^2x_n} = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{x_n} $$

and argued that this sequence converges to $0$, however then remembered that convergence to $0$ does not implicate the convergence of the series...

Then considered using the Ratio Test, but I am a bit unsure how to apply this for the specific question.
Any tips would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: Hint: for sufficiently large $n$, $L/2 <x_n < 3L/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to prove that a series converges is to find an asymptotic equivalent ($\sim$, $O$, ...) of the general term of the series. Here since $L>0$
$$
\frac{n^2}{n^4 x_n+1} \sim \frac{n^2}{n^4L}=\frac{1}{n^2L}.
$$
and using the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, we have the result.
Another way: for large $n$
$$
0 \le \frac{n^2}{n^4x_n+1} \le \frac{1}{n^2 x_n} \le \frac{1}{n^2(L/2)}.
$$
(indeed $x_n \to L$ so taking $\epsilon=L/2 >0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n \ge n_0, x_n \ge L/2$.)
And using the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, we have the result.

Comment: Thank you - the second method seems more in line with the course materials given to us thus far... Can you elaborate on why we have used $\frac{L}{2}$ though?

Comment: Just seen the edit - thank you very much! Very clear now.

Comment: @IA2307 I'm looking for $M>0$ such that $x_n > M$ in order to remove $x_n$ in $\frac{1}{n^2x_n}$ and replace it by a constant term (in order to use a comparison test). We know that $(x_n)$ converges to $L>0$ so for $\epsilon>0$ we have $L-\epsilon \le x_n \le \epsilon + L$. I need $L - \epsilon > 0$ ie. $L > \epsilon > 0$ here I choose $L/2$... My pleasure ;)